# how to clear a chart and then add data to it in swift 3 using chartView.clear()

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-charts

I am using the charts library to create a few line graphs, when there is no data available I want the graph to clear. The graph clears fine and displays its usual "nodatatext" but when I try to set the chart again the code fails on the line that sets the data: fastestChartView.data = chartData3

```
func setChart3(dataEntryX forX:[String],dataEntryY forY: [Double]) {
    fastestChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."
    var dataEntries:[ChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<forX.count{

        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y:  Double(forY[i]) , data: chugIndexArr3 as AnyObject?)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Fastest Chugs")
    chartDataSet.setColor(UIColor.green, alpha: 0.6)
    chartDataSet.circleColors = self.colors3
    chartDataSet.circleHoleColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 223/255, blue: 24/255, alpha: 1.0)

    chartData3 = LineChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    chartData3.setDrawValues(true)

    fastestChartView.data = chartData3
    fastestChartView.legend.enabled = false
    fastestChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    fastestChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: chugIndexArr3)
    fastestChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    fastestChartView.drawBordersEnabled = true
    fastestChartView.data?.setValueFormatter(valueFormatter)

    if chugIndexArr3.count > 25 {
        fastestChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 10, maxXRange: 25)
        fastestChartView.moveViewToAnimated(xValue: Double(self.chugIndexArr3.count - 25), yValue: 0, axis: .left, duration: 2)
    } else if chugIndexArr3.count == 0 {
        fastestChart.clear()
    }
    else {
        fastestChartView.resetZoom()
    }

}
```

I know that my program works because I use the same function to initially show the graph as I do when I am trying to reload the data. But for some reason when I try to use fastestChartView.clear() and then try to set the data using the same method as in the viewdidload() it crashes. Here is the code in the viewdidload() and in the button action function that causes the crash:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("chugStats").child("4avgs").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

            for index in dict.allKeys {


                let currentKey = String(describing: index)

                if currentKey != "avg" && currentKey != "fastest" {

                    let currentValue = dict[currentKey] as? String ?? ""

                    let messageArr = currentValue.components(separatedBy: ":")

                    self.chugIndexArr2.append(currentKey)
                    self.chugTimeArr2.append(Double(messageArr[0])!)
                    self.intervals2.append(Double(messageArr[1])!)

                    if let myDouble = NumberFormatter().number(from: messageArr[1])?.doubleValue {
                        let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: myDouble)
                        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
                        let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
                        self.chugInterval2.append(dateStr)
                    }

                    //Color array setup
                    if messageArr.count == 2 {
                        self.colors2.append(UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 200/255, blue: 110/255, alpha: 0.9))
                    } else if messageArr.count == 3 {
                        if messageArr[2] == "fun" {
                            self.colors2.append(UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 200/255, blue: 110/255, alpha: 0.9))
                        } else if messageArr[2] == "ranked" {
                            self.colors2.append(UIColor.red)
                        } else if messageArr[2] == "challenge" {
                            self.colors2.append(UIColor.blue)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            let sorted1 = zip(self.chugTimeArr2, self.intervals2).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
            self.chugTimeArr2 = sorted1.map { $0.0 }

            let sorted2 = zip(self.chugInterval2, self.intervals2).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
            self.chugInterval2 = sorted2.map { $0.0 }

            let sorted3 = zip(self.chugIndexArr2, self.intervals2).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
            self.chugIndexArr2 = sorted3.map { $0.0 }

            let sorted4 = zip(self.colors2, self.intervals2).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
            self.colors2 = sorted4.map { $0.0 }

        }
        self.setChart2(dataEntryX: self.chugIndexArr2, dataEntryY: self.chugTimeArr2)

    })
```

Please help me with this. I cannot find a way around it and cant find anyone who has the same problem on the internet.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. Something seems wrong with clearing the chart and probably not all variables return to their default values.

I will assume you are using Charts v3.0.3 (using 3.0.2 myself at the moment). The fix I use should be good enough.

Go to `AxisRendererBase.swift`, unlock the file if using Pods, and change line 106 (`if labelCount == 0 || range <= 0 || range.isInfinite`) to this: `if labelCount == 0 || range <= 0 || range.isInfinite || range.isNaN`.

Edit:
Created a [PR](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/2804).